# How do you change the background color of a ListTile() on tap?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, background-color, mobile-development

Very new to Flutter and I am trying to change the background color of multiple ListTiles when they are tapped. The ListTiles are a part of a Drawer and the background color is currently being set by the Container they are inside. I have seen this question asked a lot but and haven't had much luck with the solutions given. Here is some of the code I am working with:

```
Drawer normalDrawer(String route){
  return Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.archive, color: Colors.white),
              title: Text('Archived',
                  style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
              onTap: () {
                _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                    context,
                    "/archived");
                },
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: you are talking about the ripple color ?

Comment: @AhmedKhattab Not quite, it actually needs to change to a different color.